# if statements ordering based on substring length

Tags: c#

I'm running into an issue where I get ArgumentOutOfRangeException which is caused by my string being 5 characters and my substring starting at character 6. The problem is I want my code to ignore it if the substring is out of range of the string.

```
if(tok[i] == "PRINT"){
    if(tok[i+1].Substring(0,3) == "NUM"){
        Console.WriteLine(tok[i+1].Substring(4));

    }else if(tok[i+1].Substring(0,4) == "EXPR"){
        Console.WriteLine(tok[i+1].Substring(5));

    }else if(tok[i+1].Substring(0,6) == "STRING"){
        Console.WriteLine(tok[i+1].Substring(8));
    }
}
```

So my solution was to order the if statements as you see above starting from the smallest substring check to the largest substring check; however, I think there is a better way to do this that I'm missing. Any feedback is appreciated.

Inputs:

```
print "test"
print "asd"
print "last"
print 1
print 123894
```

so If I am testing for STRING first then the error will occur when it reaches "print 1" as the STRINGs Substring starts at character 8 which is greater than "print 1" which is 7 characters

Comment: I think you should use `input.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, NO_OF_CHAR))` in your if condition it will take length based on string length.

Comment: Take the length of the string before your if statements and store it in an integer variable. Add a test for that length being greater than the length of your substring.

Comment: Please provide the inputs required to cause the error and some samples of correct inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one refactoring:

```
var token = tok[i + 1];
var length = token.Length;
var start = token.SubString(0, 3);
var value = "";
if (start == "NUM")
{
    value = token.SubString(4, length - 1);
}
else if (start == "EXP")
{
    Debug.Assert(token.SubString(4, 1) == "R");
    value = token.SubString(5, length - 1);
}
else if (start == "STR")
{
    Debug.Assert(token.SubString(4, 3) == "ING");
    value = token.SubString(8, length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I suggest.

```
string[] tokens = { "NUMBER", "EXPRESSION", "STRING", "INTEGER" };

for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
    string input = tokens[i];

    if (input.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, 3)) == "NUM")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(3));
    }
    else if (input.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, 4)) == "EXPR")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(4));
    }
    else if (input.Substring(0, Math.Min(input.Length, 6)) == "STRING")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(6));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do something like this:

```
string input = "print NUM";

string[] tokens = new[] { "NUM", "EXPR", "STRING" };
var myList = new List<string>(tokens);

var searchTerm =string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? "" : input.Substring("print".Length, input.Length - "print".Length).Trim();

var pos = myList.IndexOf(searchTerm);

switch (pos)
{
// its NUM
case 0:
...
// its EXPR
case 1: 
...
// its STRING
case 2:

// not found or default
case -1:
}
```

You can also use a HashSet. It depends upon your code's performance/situation